# ClojureBox stopped working for me

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime

I am an Windows7 user, and recently downloaded ClojureBox to play around with Clojure. Everything was fine but today the clojure-mode stopped working. I can't load a file or used C-x C-e to send some clojure code from a file to the REPL. I started java, restarted my computer, reinstalled ClojureBox... and couldnt get it work!
Did someone already encountered this problem? Help appreciated!

EDIT: forgot to mention: the error I get is always: "Symbol's function definition is void: lisp=eval-last-sexp"
I also enter the command M-x clojure-mode and M-X paredit

EDIT2: I could find the solution myself: 
    `M-x clojure-enable-slime-on-existing-buffers` 
does the trick! I just need to find out what happened that preventing clojure to be enabled straight away at the start of ClojureBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody answered, I will answer with my second edit to have this questions resolved.

I could find the solution myself: `M-x clojure-enable-slime-on-existing-buffers` does the trick! I just need to find out what happened that preventing clojure to be enabled straight away at the start of ClojureBox.